# overriding a preselected bibliography style, and suppressing unwanted bibtex fields

Tags: bibliographies

I have to use a style file for a journal paper, that uses `plainnat` as its bibliography style. I want to use `abbrvnat` style, but other than directly changing the journal style file I don't know any way to select a different bibliography style. Is there a neater way to do that? I've already things like

```
\usepackage{jmlr2e} %This is the journal style that uses plainnat
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
```

without success.

Also what is the most convenient way to suppress some unwanted BibTeX fields like URL, ISBN, etc, without resorting to `biblatex`?

Comment: If the journal uses `plainnat`, then you should use that style: the editors will revert your changes anyway.

Answer (score 3):

egreg is right: If the journal class loads `plainnat`, you are supposed to use that style.

That said, here's a rather hackish way to replace `plainnat` with `abbrvnat` without changing the journal class file: Your class very like uses LaTeX's `\bibliographystyle` command to load `plainnat`. *Before loading your class*, load the `etoolbox` package (using `\RequirePackage`) and patch the `\bibliographystyle` command so that it will ignore its argument and load `abbrvnat` instead.

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\bibliographystyle}{#1}{abbrvnat}{}{}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journal = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Some text \citep{Bli74}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: The `jmlr2e` package, which is not available at CTAN, does indeed use `\bibliographystyle`.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfect. I check the published papers in the journal and there is no consistent standard for using abbreviated or full author names. I wanted to use the abbreviated version because my bibtex file doesn't have the full name for all authors.

Comment: @Alborz You may thank me by upvoting my answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and possibly accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark).